# Azure subscription name in ARM template

Tags: azure, automation, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to get Azure subscription name in the ARM template using following template

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {  },
  "variables": {
    "subscriptionName": "[subscription().displayName]"
  },
  "resources": [  ],
  "outputs": {
    "exampleOutput": {
        "value": "[variables('subscriptionName')]",
        "type" : "object"
    }
  }
}
```

Running above template using following powershell command

`New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name MyTest -ResourceGroupName EnvDev -TemplateFile C:\Users\xyz\test.json`

But getting following error

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 2:04:11 PM - {
"code": "DeploymentOutputEvaluationFailed",
"message": "Unable to evaluate template outputs: 'exampleOutput'. Please see error details and deployment operations. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
"details": [
 {
  "code": "DeploymentOutputEvaluationFailed",
  "target": "exampleOutput",
  "message": "The template output 'exampleOutput' is not valid: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.."
 }
]}
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name SentienceTest -ResourceGroup ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

How do i get the subscription name in the ARM template under which subscription its getting deployed ?

anyone know whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging on the error of your operation, I would suggest you try the following:

```
  "outputs": {
    "exampleOutput": {
        "value": "[variables('subscriptionName')]",
        "type" : "string"
    }
  }
```

So change the "type" to string.